# Using macros WIN32 or _MSC_VER cross-platform

Tags: c

I am compiling under Linux (GCC 4.4.2) and Windows VS C++ Express Edition 2008

I am currently compiling under Windows XP Pro 32 bit, and have added this to my source code.

```
#if defined( WIN32 )
/* Do windows stuff here */
#endif
```

However, the code in the if statement is disabled (grayed out). However if I do the following:

```
#if defined( _MSC_VER )
/* Do windows stuff here */
#endif
```

The if statement code is enabled.

I am just wondering, what should I be using. I have seen many programmers use WIN32. However, doesn't seem to work for me. Should I be using _MSC_VER instead?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no `WIN32`.  If you've seen it being used elsewhere, it's either wrong or the code is explicitly defining that macro itself somewhere.

You want `_WIN32`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros for a list of predefined macros in Microsoft's compiler.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me!

```
#if defined (_WIN32)
#define PLATFORM "Windows"
#elif defined (__linux)
#define PLATFORM "Linux"
#endif
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << PLATFORM << "System" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your answer in a readable way. You can see some formatting guidelines on the side bar when you are editing your post.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that for me. I'll be sure to format my code properly next time.

Answer (score 2):

Use _WIN32 instead.  The IntelliSense parser in VS2008 is troublesome, this might not necessarily solve your problem.  It got a complete rewrite in VS2010.